# How to authenticate Salesforce Users on a Drupal Site with Single Sign On?

Tags: single-sign-on, authentication, iframe

I'm a site administrator for a Drupal 7 based site. The site is integrating with an affiliate running a Salesforce site, so I need to be able to expose some content to the SF site's users. 
I have two specific cases,

1. first to be able to show some content on the SF site in an iframe and
2. Second, to give access to the Drupal site to the SF site's users.

In the first case, I would like the content to be already available to the SF site's users without having to authenticate (i.e. accept the SF site's authentication). In the second case, I simply need the users' credentials to authenticate on the Drupal site.

From my reading, implementing Single Sign On seems like the most viable option. I would think that implementing SSO would kill two birds with one stone, by providing authentication to the embedded iframe on the SF site as well as accepting the existing login credentials of the SF users on the Drupal site.

So, my question is how to set SSO for the Salesforce sites' users on the Drupal site?

Comment: Although I disagree with the assessment that the question is too broad as it asked for advice on one of two approaches to solving a problem, I've narrowed down what the question is asking.